# php, control duplicates names when generate

Tags: php, duplicates

i'm new in php. i just want to generate random names (or what you want...). it does works! but when i put in the middle of the code one "do/while" to control and avoid duplicates names it DOES NOT WORKS.... why? what's wrog with my code? i'm exhauste, destroyed.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'dbconn.php';

function getnome() {
    $nome = ['tin', 'pin', 'nid', 'din', 'vin'];

    return $nome[mt_rand(0, count($nome) - 1)];
}

for ($f =0; $f<6; $f++) {
    $arr = [];
    do {
    $x = getnome();
       }
    while (in_array($x, $arr));
    $arr[]=$x;

    $query = "INSERT INTO ants (ant_id, nome) VALUES (NULL, '".getnome()."')";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        if (!$res) {
            echo('<br>Error' . $mysqli->error);
        } else {
            echo $mysqli->affected_rows . ' created';
        }

}
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhDgs.jpg)

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with the do/while loop. It has no effect on the rest of your code.

Comment: i'm trying hard but i can't find a way to avoid duplicates names, i've try so hard but nothing. what can i do?

Comment: The easiest way to go about it would to add a unique flag to the nome column of your table, or check to see if it exists before inserting.

Comment: Why don't you just use `shuffle($nome)` to put the array in random order, then process them in an ordinary `foreach` loop?

Comment: it is working too!!!!!! really good!!!!!!!!! sir, barman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to get unique values out of an array is to randomize the array and then process it in order.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ants (nome) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $a_nome);
$nome = ['tin', 'pin', 'nid', 'din', 'vin'];
shuffle($nome);
foreach ($nome as $a_nome) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: HI, mr. Barman, i've solved with the help of Don't Panic! but i' will tryyour option, because i'm studying the pdo method .... with the PREPARE STATEMENT.! its so intresting.

Comment: @AlessandroFlorean I agree this is a better way to do it. I wanted to explain what was going wrong with the code you were using, but there are a lot of advantages to doing it this way instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems:

1. You're reinitializing `$arr` with each iteration of the for loop, so it isn't actually keeping track of the random values you've already inserted. You need to initialize it *before* the for loop.
2. You're not using the non-duplicate value of `$x` you just got in the do... while loop in your insert statement. You're calling the `getnome` function again, which will give you another (possibly duplicate) value. You need to use `$x` instead.

---

```
$arr = [];                      // initialize $arr here instead
for ($f = 0; $f < 6; $f++) {
    do {
        $x = getnome();
    }
    while (in_array($x, $arr));
    $arr[] = $x;

    // use $x instead of getnome()    
    $query = "INSERT INTO ants (ant_id, nome) VALUES (NULL, '" . $x . "')";
    $res = $mysqli->query($query);
    if (!$res) {
        echo('<br>Error' . $mysqli->error);
    } else {
        echo $mysqli->affected_rows . ' created';
    }

}
```

Another problem you'll encounter once you've fixed the other two things is that you're trying to insert six unique values, but your `getnome` function can produce only five, so it looks like the do...while loop will become infinite on the last attempt. (That may just be something that got lost in translation when you created your example, but it is a possibility with while or do...while loops that you need to be careful about.)

Comment: wow!!!!!! perfect!!!! Sir Don't Panic. i'm so happy!!!!! you save my day (night)!!!!!!!!! great! exctly i was reinitializing $arr with each iteration of the for loop. i'm sorry. too tired!!!!

Comment: lot, lot of thanks - thanks a lot - thousands times (from venice, italy)!!!!! Sir!